# What is "denying" a creep?

Tags: dota-2

My friends and I play DOTA 2 and I always wonder how do they get richer and have more EXP than me even if I did not die and they already did.
They say something about "denied thing" but they never tell me. Can someone tell me how to deny a creep?

Comment: @MBorg I don't think this is a duplicate. That already assumes you know what denying is, while the OP doesn't appear to know the term.

Comment: I took the "Can someone tell me how to deny a creep?" as how to do it. But yes you're right, I think the OP is more on how to do it within the game instead of the action to do so. My mistake

Answer (score 2):

EXP and gold you get in DOTA 2 come from landing the killing hit on an enemy, be it a player or one of the creeps, which are the minions heading towards your base. However, you ONLY get rewards from you or an ally landing the last, killing hit on an enemy mob. It doesn't matter if you did 95% of the damage yourself, only the last hit counts.

Because of that, players have come up with "denying" creeps, towers and sometimes even heroes, which is basically landing the killing hit on YOUR own minion, to deny the enemy the killing hit and associated rewards. A successful deny reduces the gold and EXP the enemy team gets to 30% EXP and no gold reward, and additionally rewards the denying player with 20% of the normal gold reward (but no EXP reward).

The DotA 2 wiki provides additional information on denying:

https://dota2.gamepedia.com/Denying

You can deny a creep, tower or hero by issuing an attack-move command directly onto the ally you want to deny. The default keybind for this is the A key.

Comment: Your answer is partially correct. Exp is always awarded, no matter who deals the killin blow. It is reduced in case of a deny, but it is not reduced when your allies strike the killing blow. Regarding gold, you are correct in most cases. Creeps only give gold to the player striking the finishing hit. But towers for example also grant gold to the rest of the team. And heroes grant gold to nearby allies. Towers and Heroes also can be denied (under certain circumstances), resulting in less/no gold (and xp) for the enemies.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that the deny rewards are changing with patches (recently it was extra exp for the denier, not gold), and briefly state conditions when denying is possible (<10% HP for towers, <50% HP for creeps, <25% and a special debuff for allies, several ways to suicide)